# s3 command for analyse

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, bucket

Suppose that you work in an e-commerce company, which keeps records of multiple products (more than a thousand) in the S3 bucket ‘records’. The files have the following structure for filename: ‘category-productid.csv’.

Now, you have to analyse the records associated with the ‘Electronics’ category only. You are expected to download the specific category reports and then perform the analysis over your local machine.

Provide the command that helps you perform this task.

i am trying on s3 help page , but i can download the csv file , but how to analyze particular category in csv ?

Comment: You can't perform any analysis with s3; it's just a storage service. You will need to use some program (eg: Excel or a custom script) to run analytics on the files once they're on your local machine.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It says "You are expected to download the specific category reports" -- you have done this. It then says "perform the analysis over your local machine", which probably means that you should do it ON your own machine. This doesn't involve any AWS service. You'll need to figure out how to analyse the CSV files yourself, because this looks like an assignment you have been given.

Answer (score 0):

aws s3 cp s3://records “local_path” --recursive --exclude “*” --include “electronics*”

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).